# Match the value of inputs on change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have two inputs which I want to have the same input values when one is typed in. It kind of works but not all the time. 
I will leave the code here:

```
$('#google-querynav').keypress(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querystat').attr('value', text);
})
$('#google-querystat').keypress(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querynav').attr('value', text);
})
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `change` and `keyup` event to do this work. Also you can use [**`val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to change value of `input` instead of `attr("value")`.

```js
$('#google-querynav').on("change keyup", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querystat').val(text);
})
$('#google-querystat').on("change keyup",function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querynav').val(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="google-querynav"/>
<input type="text" id="google-querystat"/>
```

You can use shorter code to do this

```
$('#google-querynav, #google-querystat').on("keyup change", function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querynav, #google-querystat').val(text);
})
```

Test it in [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/576f9zg4/)

Comment: Nice consolidation of the two functions! +1

Answer (score 3):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. And use `val` instead of `attr`

```js
$('#google-querynav').on('keyup change', function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querystat').val(text);
})
$('#google-querystat').on('keyup change', function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#google-querynav').val(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="google-querynav">
<input id="google-querystat">
```

Comment: `keyup` event isn't enough to do this. If user past text in input using mouse, it doesn't work. You need to use `change` event also for change text using mouse.

Comment: @KevBot Well. Now, what is difference of your code with my code? :)

Comment: @Mohammad, yours was there first. :)